# drop a visio shape based on external XY coordinates

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, visio

I have a csv file that lists X and Y coordinates for various polygons. I have a master shape called "Polygon" with some features like area and name in the text field.

Sample of csv file:

[image: CSV File Sample Image]

These are 2 squares shapes, one with its bottom left corner at 0,0 and other one at 5,5.

The question is, how do I plot this, using my "Polygon" master, such that it takes up the coordinates listed in the table.  So one "Polygon" will be at 0,0 and other at 5,5.

"FID" is a unique number in sequence that helps identify the next point. "Shape#" helps to identify for which shape the coordinate belongs to. For e.g: Shape# 1 has 4 vertices (0,0; 1,0; 1,1; 0,1) and the 5th vertex (0,0 again) closes the shape. The "FID" helps in determining the sequence of these vertices i.e. 1,1 comes after 1,0 and not vice-versa.

So, if I want to plot Shape# 1, it will be a square with sides of 1 unit.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The C# example below might help you. It doesn't use masters and dropping but this should roughly accomplish what you need.

```
        var data = new[]
        {
            new {FID = 0, ShapeNum = 1, X = 0.0, Y = 0.0},
            new {FID = 1, ShapeNum = 1, X = 1.0, Y = 0.0},
            new {FID = 2, ShapeNum = 1, X = 1.0, Y = 1.0},
            new {FID = 3, ShapeNum = 1, X = 0.0, Y = 1.0},
            new {FID = 4, ShapeNum = 1, X = 0.0, Y = 0.0},
            new {FID = 5, ShapeNum = 2, X = 5.0, Y = 5.0},
            new {FID = 6, ShapeNum = 2, X = 6.0, Y = 5.0},
            new {FID = 7, ShapeNum = 2, X = 6.0, Y = 6.0},
            new {FID = 8, ShapeNum = 2, X = 5.0, Y = 6.0},
            new {FID = 9, ShapeNum = 2, X = 5.0, Y = 5.0}
        };


        // group by shapenum
        var data2 = from record in data
            group record by record.ShapeNum
            into g
            select new {ShapeNum = g.Key, Records = g}
            ;

        var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.ApplicationClass();
        var doc = app.Documents.Add("");
        var page = doc.Pages[1];

        foreach (var g in data2)
        {
            var sorted_records = g.Records.OrderBy(i => i.FID).ToList();
            var doubles = new List<double>();

            foreach (var r in sorted_records)
            {
                doubles.Add(r.X);
                doubles.Add(r.Y);
            }

            page.DrawPolyline(doubles.ToArray(), 0);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Saveenr. How to I make use of a *.csv file to get the coordinates? The table I have shown is an external dataset and there are more than 2 shapes.